# Which value for "WindowsOSVersion" in an ARM template?

Tags: azure, powershell, templates, virtual-machine, azure-resource-manager

I want to create an Azure VM from an ARM Template. The "windowsOSVersion" parameter looks like the following

```
    "windowsOSVersion": {
  "type": "string",
  "defaultValue": "Windows-10",
  "metadata": {
    "description": "Description"
  }
}
```

I'm not sure whether value is right, thats the first potential mistake. 
I'm providing other information about the OS in the Template in "variables":

```
"imagePublisher": "MicrosoftWindowsDesktop",
"imageOffer": "windows-10",
```

When I run my PowerShell script I'm getting this error:

```
Template deployment returned the following errors:
15:39:23 - Resource Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines 'MyWindowsVM' failed with message '{
  "error": {
    "code": "ImageNotFound",
    "message": "The platform image 'MicrosoftWindowsDesktop:windows-10:Windows10:latest' is not available. Verify that all fields in the storage profile are correct.",
    "target": "imageReference"
  }
```

The error is self-explaining, but I don't know which value I do have to change (I'm sure the "imagePublisher" and the "imageOffer" variables values are right).

I tried to remove the "windowsOSVersion" parameter, but it is required.

Do you have any Idea?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find out this information using these powershell cmdlets:

```
Get-AzVmImagePublisher -Location northeurope
Get-AzVMImageOffer -PublisherName 'MicrosoftWindowsDesktop' -Location northeurope
Get-AzVMImageSku -PublisherName 'MicrosoftWindowsDesktop' -Offer 'windows-10' -Location northeurope
```

here's the list in your case:

```
RS3-Pro
rs3-pro-test
RS3-ProN
rs4-pro
rs4-pron
rs5-evd
rs5-pro
rs5-pron
```